# Broadcom 43455 WiFi adapter problems

Tags: networking, broadcom

Raspberry Pi3 B+ running Raspbian Stretch 2018-03-13
Broadcom 43455 WiFi adapter connects to network but won't pass any traffic.  If I connect an Asus dongle, that works perfectly once I turn off Wlan0 (the Brcm).
I have run the pi-update and tried removing and re-probing the driver.
modprobe -r brcmfmac
modprobe brcmfmac
and rebooted with no luck. ifconfig shows wlan0 has an ip address and is connected - it just won't pass any traffic.

Help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using a fresh flashed `Raspbian Stretch 2018-03-13`. It's [release notes](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/release_notes.txt) says:

> - WiFi is disabled until wireless regulatory domain is set (Pi 3 B+ only)
>
>   - The domain can be done through 'Raspberry Pi Configuration' (rc_gui),
>       'raspi-config' or by setting 'country=' to an appropriate ISO 3166
>       alpha2 country code in /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf.

Please add a `country=` line to your `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.